# Creating a world background different from the HDRi

Tags: hdri

Recently I was trying to figure out the following in Cycles: I was using HDRi file A to light my scene, but I desired to have only HDRi file B visible in the background (i.e. using an HDRi of a daytime field to light the objects in the scene, but seeing a starfield in the background). I've been unable to figure this out—would anybody mind pointing out how this sort of effect could be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!